# Do Windows 10 phones still glitching (in 2016)?

Tags: lumia, windows-10-mobile, android

I’ve seen several bad reviews about Windows 10 phones. Is it still unstable in 2016 ? How could you compare it’s quality to Android’s ?

Comment: it has greatly improved over the past few months, but still very buggy in 512mb ram devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reliability of Windows 10 mobile has greatly improved in 2016. In my low end Lumia (Lumia 430) the performance is on par with the same cost Android phone.

Most of those reviews were written during the release of 950XL. Windows 10 Mobile is receiving monthly updates. These updates are mainly bug fixes and performance improvements. The Anniversity Update has added many small features. Most of the core apps are updated on a weekly basis(patch Tuesday). Yes, Windows 10 Mobile is improving with every update. This has benefited everyone as all eligible devices are being updated unlike Android.